# Assigning all the attributes of an element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have written this code to replace all the elements of a page having a specific data attribute with a dropdown. Let's say if I have had:

```
<span data-what="partyBox"></span>
```

It will be replaced with a dropdown. The code works well but with an exception; later on I wanted to assign all the attributes (for example all the data attributes or anyother assigned ones) of the current tag i.e. the `span` tag in this case to be assigned to the dropdown that I created. But I am having problem to attain this i.e. it doesn't apply all these attributes to the dropdown. Here is my code:

```
var mould = {

    partyBox        :   $.parseHTML('<select name="mouldedParty"><option value="-1" selected disabled>Select Party</option></select>'),

    init            :   function (){ },

    process         :   function (container) {
                            var pBox     = $(mould.partyBox);
                            var pBoxes   = $(container).find('[data-what=partyBox]');

                            pBox.css({
                                'padding'    : '10px',
                                'border'     : '1px solid #ccc',
                                'background' : '#368EE0',
                                'color'      : 'white',
                                'cursor'     : 'pointer'
                            });

                            $(pBoxes).each(function(index, elem){
                                var attributes = elem.attributes;
                                var test = $(elem).replaceWith(pBox);
                                test.attributes = attributes;

                            });

                            // pBoxes.replaceWith(pBox);

                        }
};

mould.process('body');
```

Can anybody please tell me what's wrong with this code? Why doesn't it apply all the attributes of the span tag to dropdown, although I have used these lines for replacement

```
            var attributes = elem.attributes;
            var test = $(elem).replaceWith(pBox);
            test.attributes = attributes;
```

Comment: You're setting the `attributes` property of a random jQuery object which ceases to exist as soon as the function finishes executing (so after that line). You want to be setting the `attributes` property of the actual element, so you'll need to figure out a way to get a reference to that new element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the `attributes` property of an element. All you can do is copy attributes from one element to another.

Code like this might be a solution:

```
$(pBoxes).each(function (index, elem) {
    var newBox = pBox.clone(true, true)[0]; // get a simple DOM element

    // loop through the old element's attributes and give them to the new element
    for (var name in elem.attributes) {
        newBox.setAttribute(name, elem.attributes[name].value);
    }

    // replace the old element with the new one
    var test = $(elem).replaceWith(newBox);
});
```

I admit I'm finding your code a little confusing, so I can't 100% guarantee that my code will suit your purpose...